# What is learnt in electrical engineering undergraduate courses?

Tags: education

Can anyone provide me some example link that points what is studied in electrical engineering major at undergraduate level?

Also, how is graduate one different from undergraduate one?

Note: I'm asking this question because I'm not engineering major.

Comment: Not enough to actually be proficient at building simple circuits or assemble boards by hand. :P I kid, I kid!

Answer (score 3):

Courses differ from one school to another. I'm an undergrad at Northeastern University. Main topics include physics, calculus, linear systems (how signals act, noise in systems), digital/analog components and design, electromagnetic fields and programming.

An undergraduate degree is a little bit of everything. A graduate degree is much more focused on one topic.

Answer (score 2):

Most schools publish their syllabus and have quite detailed subject descriptions linked to them, you will have to dig through the website of the schools you are interested in.  For example, my alma-mater [The University of Newcastle's is here](http://www.newcastle.edu.au/program/10173.html) and [MIT's is here](http://student.mit.edu/catalog/m6a.html).

What one school offers compared to another can vary quite significantly, especially in the later years.  In addition programs generally offer a number of selective subjects that allow students to choose between different subjects depending on their interests, so what one student studies will vary from another, even if they attend the same school.

Answer (score 1):

By no means a comprehensive list, basically off the top of my head:

You will often find one way or another and with different names, broken down or grouped together:

- Lots of Math (calculus, linear algebra, differential equations, discrete math (difference equations, numerical methods)).
- Statistics
- Lots of Physics (classic/newtonian, optics, quantum & semiconductor physics)
- Chemistry (especially organic chemistry).
- Mechanical machines (gears, motors, generators, etc).
- Technical drawing.
- Programming (operating systems, algorithms, assembly language, c language)
- Communication Systems
- Digital Systems
- Electromagnetic Theory
- Electrical Circuits (RLC circuits, transformers, two-port circuits, etc)
- Electronic Circuits (diodes, transistors, op-amps, oscillators, power supplies, transmission lines, etc).
- Microelectronics
- Microprocessors
- Automatic Control Systems.
- Power Systems
- Networks
- Instrumentation
- Digital signal processing.

Many of the above with their respective laboratories.

Some elective courses are:

Robotics, neural networks, fpga design, VLSI, VHDL, digital image processing, non-linear control, among many, many others, depending on the school.

You may also find sprinkled some courses that are not exactly engineering but are part of your formation as a professional, such as economics, project management, etc.

Comment: Why is Organic chemistry is in EE course ?